# SQLalchemy keyword argument equivalent of `Column('id', Integer, Identity())`

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Attempt: `Column(name='id', type_=Integer, default=Identity())`

I'm looking at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Identity and [https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.**init**](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.__init__) but I can't see what the equivalent would be, I tried `default=Identity()` but got a:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: ColumnDefault may not be a server-side default type.

Am I meant to use https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html#sqlalchemy.schema.DefaultClause or `sqlalchemy.schema.DefaultGenerator`? - Or is it not meant to be a `default=`/equivalent at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass `Indentity()` as a keyword argument, use `server_default`:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2:///test', echo=True, future=True)
t = sa.Table(
    't', sa.MetaData(), sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, server_default=sa.Identity(), primary_key=True)
)
t.create(engine)
```

Output

```
2022-12-18 21:27:32,265 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
2022-12-18 21:27:32,266 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine 
CREATE TABLE t (
    id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

...
```

[Source code on GitHub](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/b924ba949cb8aa1bd73f7438600caf92a3b732b3/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py#L2021)

Comment: Thanks and does [`sqlalchemy.types.Enum`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum) go in the sample place?